# Java Style XML one node per line and no whitespace

Tags: java, xml

Just fooling with removing whitespace but keeping each node on its own line from an xml document when adding and removing elements from xml in java and I'm having trouble understanding XML Style Sheets.

Here is what's happening so far.

Firstly I have the following XML,

```
<jobs>
   <job>Job 1</job>
   <job>Job 2</job>
   <job>Job 3</job>
   <job>Job 4</job>
</jobs>
```

Then I remove one of the elements and it ends up looking like this with the whitespacewhere the element was,

```
<jobs>
   <job>Job 1</job>

   <job>Job 3</job>
   <job>Job 4</job>
</jobs>
```

So I tried applying the following style sheet I found,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which makes the xml appear on one line because it removes all whitespace. But I'm trying to keep the file readable too.

```
<jobs><job>Job 1</job><job>Job 2</job><job>Job 3</job><job>Job 4</job></jobs>
```

I was wondering if anyone has a style sheet to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `indent="yes"` to `<xsl:output`:

`<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>`

(Also, you might want to switch to XSL Version 2.0)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it. Worked exactly as I was after.